# XSLT Transform of Razor Output

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, xslt, razor, httpmodule

I want to use XSLT to perform an HTML-to-HTML transform.  The catch is, I want that transformation step done *after* the razor view engine is "done" rendering and before the response is sent back to the client.

I see a [post that deals with response transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281173/how-can-i-perform-xslt-transformations-in-an-httpmodule), but I'm not sure if there is a better extension point for this, or if something about the Razor response would make that particular HttpModule impossible.  If that example HttpModule is the right idea, is it the right technique?

I just want some insights *before* I invest a lot of time into this.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
using (var sw = new StringWriter())
{
    var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, "ViewName", null);
    var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, view.ViewData, view.TempData, sw);

    viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

    var html = sw.ToString();
}
```